# Insert another field into GET response JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following code that responds to `GET /something.json`:

```
def index
  @something = Something.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @something }
  end
end
```

That runs a `SELECT * FROM something` in the database, formats the result into a JSON, and responds with it.

The request might ask for another field through a query parameter, which is in a different table than `something`. I managed to retrieve the desired field doing this:

```
def index
  @something = Something.all

  if params[:get_field_from_some_other_table] == "true"
    @something.each do |i|
        some_other_table = SomeOtherTable.find(i.some_other_table_id)
        the_field_i_want = some_other_table.the_field
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @something }
  end
end
```

But I haven't found a way to add the field to the JSON string. How can I do that? Or is there a better way to retrieve the field with the contents of the `something` table through a `JOIN` or something like that?

Comment: Its very unclear what you are trying to do, it might help if you present the actual problem you are trying to solve instead of any extremely abstracted version.

Answer (score 1):

`something` and `other_table` should be related at active_record somehow... maybe a `has_one`?
Try that and then just use `@something.all.includes(:other_table_attribute)`

Apart from that, please post your code properly with some readable examples, that helps a lot and will give you faster responses :)